# Split a string and convert individual pieces to hexadecimal

Tags: c, string, hex, strtol

I have a string like `"03FE"` holding hexadecimal values. I need to split this string in two parts, and convert each individual part to the equivalent hexadecimal.

That is, I need `0x03` in one variable and `0xFE` in another variable.

For example, if I didn't have to split the string, this is how I would have done it:

```
 char *p;
 uint32_t uv=0;
 uv=strtoul(&string_to_convert, &p, 16);
```

How shall I proceed if I needed to split the string?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hexa variable". The variable contains an integer. The "hexadecimal" part is just way to present that integer to humans, as a string. The integer itself is not hex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the output of `strtoul` instead:

```
uint8_t uv_hi = uv >> 8;
uint8_t uv_lo = uv & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

- You can create one additional buffer  of length `n+1`, where you want to split the string into `n` byte tokens
- Use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to print out `n` characters to the temporary buffer.
- Use [`strtoul()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) to convert the temporary buffer content to hex value.
- Iterate over till you have tokens left.

This way, you can have a generic approach to tokenize and convert a source string of *any* length into tokens and then convert them to hex values.